# Enterprise Library Caching in isolated store accessible to different apps

Tags: asp.net, caching, enterprise-library

Good day.

I'm wondering if the Enterprise Library Caching using isolated storage (disk, not DB) can be accessed by multiple apps in IIS? That is , can they all share the same instance of it.

I have various WCF services running on one machine, set up in different web apps (and potentially in different app pools, if that makes a difference). They all need access to a shared cache.

I had been told that this is possible with EntLib, but after doing some reading I'm not entirely sure this is the case. All of the services are running under NETWORK SERVICE user, but since they are all different apps in IIS does this prevent the sharing? I know having a different user certainly would.

So, can the same user use the same cache across multiple apps, or is it limited to within one app?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using EntLib for this and just used isolated storage.

In case anybody has the same problem, you can see the following question where I posted the code I used, as well as an issue I hit while using it plus the resolution.

[Can't share isolated storage file between applications in different app pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649947/cant-share-isolated-storage-file-between-applications-in-different-app-pools)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share your cache across several services it would be better to go with App Fabric caching. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx

Comment: Thanks, and I'll look into that for the future. However, that seems much heavier than I have time to get in to right now.I have all of my caching code written already for Enterprise Library and it is nontrivial to get new things added to the test environment. Do you know if Enterprise Library will do what I need?